# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Estoy creando un archivo php de búsqueda y tengo el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, null given in /volume1/web/recibos/pages/search.php on
>   line 127

He realizado varios cambios y consultado varios foros pero no encuentro la solución.

El error sólo ocurre cuando se llama a la función `all`.

```
function all($search_result){
$query  = mysqli_query("select * from recibos");
$search_result = filterTable($query);
$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
}
```

El error me aparece en la siguiente línea:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
```

Con otra query funciona perfectamente, sin embargo no al listar todo.

Expongo todo el código por si alguien puede ayudarme.

```html
<?php

 $output='';
 
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
 $field = $_POST['field'];
 if ($field == "seguro") {
  $field_db = "type";
  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field_db LIKE '%".$busqueda."%'";
  $search_result = filterTable($query);
  $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
 
} elseif ($field=="tax"){
   
  $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field='1'";
  $search_result = filterTable($query);
  $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

} elseif ($field=="renta"){
   
  //$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field='1'");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field='1'";
  $search_result = filterTable($query);
  $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
   
  
}elseif (isset($_POST['see_all'])){
  all($search_result);
    
 
}elseif ($count_rows = 0){
 $output = "Your search query doesn't match any data!";
}else{
 all($search_result);
}
}

function all($search_result){
 $query  = mysqli_query("select * from recibos");
 $search_result = filterTable($query);
 $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
}

 function filterTable($query){
  include ('connection.php');
  $filter_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
  return $filter_result;
 }

 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Recibos</title>

<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width. intial-scale=1.0">-->
<meta name="busqueda_recibos" content="busqueda de Recibos">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
 <style>
  table,tr,th,td{
   border:1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
 <div >
  <div>
  <picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 602px) and (max-width: 800px)" srcset="../images/recibo-movil.png">
   <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="../images/recibo-movil.png">
   <img src="../images/recibo.png" alt="Recibos">
  </picture>
  </div>

  <div>
   <h1>Busqueda de recibos</h1>
  </div>

  
 </div>
 <div>
 <center>
  <form action="search.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <br><br><br>
  Busquedas:
     <select name="field" id="field">
        <option value="de">De</option>
        <option value="seguro">Seguros</option>
        <option value="tax">Impuestos</option>
        <option value="renta">Renta</option>
     </select><br><br>
   Para buscar todo escribe asterisco *.:
   <input type="text" name="busqueda" placeholder="*" size="25" maxlength="25" /><br><br>
   
   Opcional. Busquedas por cantidad:
   Desde : <input  type="number" name="quantity_from" min="0" value="0" step=".01" /> A: <input  type="number" name="quantity_to" min="0" value="0" step=".01" /><br><br>
   
   Opcional. Busquedas por fechas:
   Desde : <input type="date" name="ticket_date_from" /> A: <input type="date" name="ticket_date_to" /><br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit-search" value="Buscar" />
   <input type="reset">
   <input type="submit" name="see_all" value="Ver todo" />
   
   
   <table>
    <tr>
     <th>Id.</th>
     <th>Núm. factura</th>
     <th>De</th>
     <th>Fecha factura</th>
     <th>Cantidad</th>
     <th>Tipo</th>
     <th>Seguro</th>
     <th>Dirección</th>
     <th>Fecha ingreso</th>
     <th>Documento</th>
     <th>Impuesto</th>
     <th>Renta</th>
     <th>Descripción</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
    <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['ticket_index']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['ticket_number']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['ticket_from']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['ticket_date']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['type_insurance']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['type_address']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['ticket_ts']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['image_dir']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['tax']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['renta']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
     endwhile;
     //mysqli_free_result($search_result); // Liberamos los registros
     //mysqli_close($conn); // Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos
    ?>
   </table>
  </form>
 </center>
 </div>
</div>
<?php

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estoy viendo que cuando entra por la opcion de "see all" del if , le estas pasando a la funcion *all*  la variable *$search_result* que en ese momento tiene valor nulo. Esto es porque no le das un valor por defecto antes del if y en las que el usuario si escoge una opcion a éste ya le stas asignando un valor. Poreso te funciona con las demás opciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Hello. Se lo que me estás diciendo pero no sé donde añadirlo para que se pueda pintar en el html. He llamado a la función desde antes del primer if pero tampoco funciona. No puedo realizar  ver el valor de las variables dado que estoy con notepad++ y no entiendo mucho de php.

Answer (score 0):

La variable **$search_result** en sí no la necesitas para realizar esa sentencia **select**, ya que ésta no influye en el proceso, es decir, si la variable **$search_result** tuviera un id de algún producto y lo necesitases para realizar la sentencia entonces si lo pasas como parámetro.

En tu caso no la necesitas por lo que yo lo quitaría, de este modo te quedaría la llamada de la función de la siguiente manera:

```
}else{
 all(); //quitamos el parámetro ya que no te sirve
}
```

Luego la función te quedaría de esta manera:

```
function all(){ //quitamos el parámetro
  $query  = mysqli_query("select * from recibos");
  $search_result = filterTable($query);
  $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result); //le pasamos $search_result que es dodne tienes la consulta
}
```

Si te sigue fallando coméntale para ver si te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Muchas gracias Hello There. Lo arregle eliminando la función y añadiendo en el último else 

}else{
    $query  = "select * from recibos";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

}

Con esto ya me fue suficiente para lo que necesitaba. 

Ahora fallan otras cosas pero seguiré con ello con más tiempo.

Muchas gracias Hello.